# "you're just trying to farm reputation here" Is it constructive

Tags: discussion

I have got a comment from a  user:

The part of the [comment](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-to-install-ccleaner-in-elementary-os#comment6220_3568) is:

" it seems like you're just trying to farm reputation here"

I know the comment is *very constructive*, but the part of it which I mentioned is not.

Reference to [shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) answer: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments)

> - **not constructive**: this is pretty much a superset of "rude and offensive". Even if you don't personally find them offensive, those one-liner contests are often good examples of non constructive comments: "pithy" jokes at the authors' expense, "snarky" advice meant more to score points with the commenter's peers than to inform or educate, and **tangential personal observations all fall into this category**. Again, flag these wherever you find them. I feel that is not constructive to address other user in SE.

I flagged it as "non-constrctive"

The flag is declined with **no reason**.

I would like to know the reason.

Comment: I believe only mods decline the flags, then why there is no reply to this post? @RolandiXor

Comment: Who was this user

Comment: 'this user" what? @SuiciDoga  :)

Comment: The user that wrote the comment

Answer (score 2):

Well with an eye to keeping it simple, it did appear to me that he was correct in his observation *at the time when handling the flag*.

Since the entire comment seemed relevant and constructive, I declined the flag. Of course you are free to disagree and explain why you disagree.

However, just keep in mind that your response didn't help your case, to be 100% honest.

Comment: who is "he"? the commenter? sorry, but tbh I don't understand your 100% honesty.